# Search values if It exists Under Same Column value : Mysql

Tags: mysql

### Column 1 - Column 2

A1 ------- P11

B1 ------- D34

C1 ------- F56

A1 ------- P24

C1 ------- P45

Lets say, I need to find the value of COLUMN 1 where P11 and P24 under same value of COLUMN 1. Here : A1, A1 have both P11 and P24.

I need to find this using mysql query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested, off the top of my head:

```
SELECT   column1
 WHERE   column2 IN ('p11', 'p24')
GROUP BY column1
HAVING   COUNT(column1) == 2
```

I'm assuming you want all column1's that have BOTH values in your list.